# Why does Time Machine need a Spotlight index of the backup?

Tags: backup, time-machine, spotlight

This subject has been touched on here, but in my opinion not answered at all.

I'm trying to understand why Time Machine needs Spotlight. It's widely stated that it does but never explained why. I can't think of a reason. What would be the effect of never letting Spotlight complete its indexing of the Time Machine backup?

My context: I'm backing up a new M1 Macbook Pro, and a new M2 Macbook Air, to separate USB SSD drives. This is a temporary measure until I get a new WiFi backup device. I'm doing it manually about every one or two days. So I plug in the USB drive and when the backup finishes the disk keeps flashing away and various `md` processes are very busy - `mdsync`, `mdworker_shared`, `mds`. Usually, I just unmount and pull out the USB drive. Nothing seems to go wrong, and I can still remount it and "Enter Time Machine" and recover some files I need. (I'll swap to a new WiFi backup device sometime soon, I don't want to trust my many-years-old Time Capsule any longer). So I don't have any idea why Time Machine **needs** Spotlight. There must be many scenarios where the user backs up and then disconnects the drive, as above. In fact, it would be forced on you in some scenarios, eg. a shared backup drive across several Macs. For example, I might decide to use a single SSD USB drive for both the Macs mentioned above. It wouldn't be feasible to sit and wait for Spotlight to finish an interminable indexing operation when I need to pull out the drive and back up the other Mac.

I'd like to understand this to be sure I'm not exposed to any risk here. Many thanks.

(Hope this question satisfies the moderators. I've read all the suggested related items, and many others on other sites, and I've not found the answer).

Comment: How would the Time machine know which files have changed and which one need back up

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It is possible that some Time Machine internals require Spotlight, but this could simply be a design decision to let users search and restore files using Spotlight when browsing Time Machine backups, see this knowledge base article "Recover files using Time Machine and Spotlight on Mac (https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/recover-files-time-machine-spotlight-mh15136/12.0/mac/12.0).

Comment: Thanks @Ruskes. AFAIK Time Machine uses FS events to log file changes. That doesn't require any Spotlight use.

Comment: Thanks @jaume. I learned something there. You can go into the File / Revert To menu in some apps, like TextEdit, and enter a mini Time Machine window and go back to earlier versions of a file. Could be useful occasionally.

Comment: Well I have come up myself with a scenario where a Spotlight Index of your TM' backups might be useful. Say you had a file "important.notes.30sep22.txt" and it was backed up by TM, then you accidentally deleted it, and you don't remember what folder it was in, and all you can remember is that its name was "important.notes" .. blah. A Spotlight index of your TM backups could be the only or certainly fastest way to find it, and restore it. I've never needed that though, the handful of times I needed to get something back from TM I knew exactly what I needed. Might have a use one day.